# Do Anyone Have a Working Example of Using Amazon S3 and SimpleDB with Android?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm interested in uploading data (images mostly) from my Android App to Amazon S3 and then storing its reference into a Amazon SimpleDB (with other data).

Do anyone have a working example that takes an image and some data (text, etc) from an app and uploads the image to S3 and stores the reference to the image and the data into a SimpleDB for later retrieval?

I've been going through the Amazon SDK for Android and looking at their examples and reading what I can find on the subject but I can't seem to find a good example that I can understand and implement.

Thanks!

Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this article that shows how to upload images to S3 using the Amazon Android SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/Android/3002109349624271

Answer (score 0):

use below class to upload images on amazon s3 server and get URL string of uploaded image. make sure you are giving correct region name. to identify your region name reffer below URL

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

and put this dependency in build.gradle

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.1'

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ResponseHeaderOverrides;    
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class UploadImageToAmazonServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private String selectImages = "";
    private String imageName;
    ArrayList<File> imagesArray;
    WebServiceInterface<String, String> mInterface;

    public UploadImageToAmazonServer(Context context, String imageName, ArrayList<File> imagesArray) {

        mContext = context;
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.imagesArray = imagesArray;
    }

    public void result(WebServiceInterface<String, String> myInterface) {
        this.mInterface = myInterface;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.Access_Key, Constants.Secret_Access_Key));
s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
     //   s3Client.setEndpoint("ap-south-1");
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesArray.size(); i++) {
            try {
                String imagePath =  imageName;
                PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest("bucketname/foldername", imagePath, imagesArray.get(i));
                s3Client.putObject(por);
                ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
                override.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                //publishProgress(30);
                GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("bucketname/foldername", imagePath);
                urlRequest.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000));  // Added an hour's worth of milliseconds to the current time.
                urlRequest.setResponseHeaders(override);
                url=s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
                if (i != imagesArray.size() - 1) {
                    selectImages = selectImages + url + "|";
                } else {
                    selectImages = selectImages + url;
                }

            } catch (com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException amazonExp) {
                Log.d("setImageSync", amazonExp.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        return selectImages;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //   Utils.hideDialog();
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Utility.hideProgressBar();
        mInterface.success(this.selectImages);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Utility.showProgressDialog(mContext);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... vaIntegers) {
//        progressBar.setProgress(vaIntegers[0]);

    }

    public interface WebServiceInterface<E, R> {
        public void success(E reslut);

        public void error(R Error);
    }
}
```

If you have more number of images then go for service instead of AsycTask

Answer (score -1):

1. Please download [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) and [SDExplorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/). Bucket Explorer is the tool for Amazon s3 and SDB Explorer is tool for Amazon SimpleDB. They can be downloaded free for 30 days.
2. Try to [upload image uisng Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-upload-file-to-s3.html).
3. Try to [Generate web url of multipe uploaded image on single click](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-file.html).
4. Copy all URL to textpad at local file system and save file as csv.
5. Run SDB Explorer and [Import data from CSV](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-upload-csv-file-data-with-auto-generated-item-name.html).

For more reference -

1. http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--more-simpledbexplorer-product-manual-detail.html
2. http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--more-product-manual-detail.html
3. http://gallery.bucketexplorer.com/
4. http://gallery.sdbexplorer.com/